# General form of a symplectic map

Tags: reference-request, hilbert-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics

A symplectic automorphism of a Hilbert space has the form $T=U(\cosh S+J\sinh S)$ for a unitary $U$, an antilinear involution $J$ and a positive operator $S$. In fact a version of this goes through in the unbounded case (see Squeezing Bogoliubov transformations on the infinite mode CCR-algebra,
Honegger and Rieckers, Com. Math. Phys. 37 no. 9 (1996) )

*Question: Does a similar result hold for a (not necessarily surjective) symplectic map $T:H\to K$ between Hilbert spaces?*

(The reference I have relies pretty heavily on $T$ having dense range)

Comment: (every separable h.sp. is necessarily isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$, right? So, perhaps *in this case* the forumla you're looking for is just the one you posted, "conjugated" by the relevant isomorphisms..)

Comment: (...I mean, if both $H$ and $\mathrm{range}(T)$ are both $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$) 

Comment: The range of the symplectic map is only a real-linear subspace, so the corresponding isomorphisms may not be complex-linear, this is a problem for me. Also I'm interested in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: (as well as the infinite dimensional..)

Comment: In the case that $T$ is continuous, there holds for all $x,y \in H$ $$\langle Jx, y\rangle = \langle JTx,Ty\rangle = \langle T^\dagger J T x, y \rangle \Leftrightarrow T^\dagger J T = J.$$ (or do you have another definition of symplectic?)
In that case you get $${T^\dagger}^{-1} = - J T J$$ and you see, that $T$ must be an automorphism.

Comment:  My definition of symplectic is $Im\langle Tx,Ty\rangle=Im\langle x,y\rangle$ - i.e. the symplectic form comes from the inner-product structure on the Hilbert space. Thus we can definitely have symplectic maps which are not automorphisms.

Comment: Hm, ok, let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Define $$g(x,y) := \Re \langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,x \rangle \right)$$ and $$\omega(x,y) = \Im \langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \langle x,y \rangle - \langle y,x \rangle \right)$$. Than clearly $g$ is symmetric and positive definite and $$\omega(x,y) = g(i x,y).$$

Let $T: H \to H$ be symplectic, i.e. for all $x,y \in H\times H$ there holds $$\omega(Tx,Ty) = \omega(x,y),$$ then there holds for all $x,y \in H \times H$ $$g(iTx,Ty) = g(ix,y).$$

Comment: Let $T^\dagger$ be the (real) adjoint Operator with respect to $g$, i.e. for all $x,y \in H\times H$ holds $$g(Tx,y) = g(x,T^\dagger y),$$ then, like in my comment above, $$T^{-1} = - i T^\dagger i.$$

I don't know how to proceed, if T is not continous, since you have to take a lot of care, on the definitions set of $T$ and $T^\dagger$.

Kind regards
Konstantin

Comment: Ah yes, you've shown it has a left inverse - but it may not be an automorphism. Consider the right shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ (which is symplectic). Clearly $-iS^*iS=S^*S=1$, but it is not surjective, so not invertible. Thanks for the interest though

Comment: oh yes, you're right. it's just a left inverse...
How does one show $T = U ( \cos S + J \sin S)$? Clearly one has the polar decomposition $T = UR$ with $U$ (partial) unitary and self adjoint $R$ with $R^2 = T^\dagger T$. Since this decomposition holds for every $T$ (also unbounded one). Maybe you can use the same construction for T, that are not surjective? (We know now, that they are injective.)